# monodroid: cannot deploy to emulator with evaluation version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I followed all the descriptions of "how to build a hello word app with monodroid and vs2010. When I deploy solution by pressing F5 and select the emulator, the emulator starts up, I can select it from the device list, the packaging starts, but gets an error said:**Could not create the Android package**. See the Output (Build) window for more details.
In the output window, I can see the following message (the complete message had been added to the end of the question):
**...monodroid : error 1: Evaluation version requires targeting the shared runtime...**

Anyone can help to gets work it?

Thanks forward: Zsolt

Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.225]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 2011.05.05. 11:12:38.
Project "c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).
_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
  Looking for Android SDK..
    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
      Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk).
  Looking for Java SDK..
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\CurrentVersion found: 1.6.
    Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6\JavaHome found:
      Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25).
  MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\
  MonoAndroid Framework: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\
  Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
  Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\
_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
  GetAndroidPackageName Task
    ManifestFile: 
    AssemblyName: MonoAndroidApplication1
    PackageName: MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1
_UpdateAndroidResgen:
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  MonoAndroidApplication1 -> c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Release\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll
_CompileAndroidPackage:
  Mandroid Task
    Assemblies: c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Release\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    I18nAssemblies: 
    BuildDirectory: c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Release\
    ReferenceAssembliesDirectory: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\;;
    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
    JavaSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\
    AssetDirectory: c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Release\assets\
    AndroidSdkPlatform: 8
    MonoAndroidToolsDirectory: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\
    ResourceDirectory: c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Release\res\
    ManifestTemplate: 
    Package: MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1
    NativeLibrary: 
    JavaSource: 
    Debug: False
    UseSharedRuntime: False
    SupportedAbis: armeabi
    LinkMode: SdkOnly
    ExtraArgs:
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe -v --nosign --sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" --builddir="c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Release\android" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" -S="c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\obj\Release\res" --package="MonoAndroidApplication1.MonoAndroidApplication1"   --linksdkonly --noshared --abi="armeabi" --java-sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25" --sdk-platform="8" "c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\bin\Release\MonoAndroidApplication1.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
monodroid : error 1: Evaluation version requires targeting the shared runtime. [c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj]
Done Building Project "c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

**"c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
(_CompileAndroidPackage target) -> 
  monodroid : error 1: Evaluation version requires targeting the shared runtime. [c:\documents and settings\zsolt\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1\MonoAndroidApplication1.csproj]**

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.46

Error: Cancelled
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I guess you should target the shared runtime in the project properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem -I think- is the same as mine.
I had a special character in the projects Location (C:\Users\bálint...).
Try to create a new project, and set the Location something simple, like C:\Work\, and probably you can avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had too a similar issue. In my case the problem was the package name. I had a special character in the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out to be that although I had purchased the Xamarin Mono for Android software, I had not registered it in Visual Studio 2010. I had installed it but had not registered it.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into same situation and i found a solution  i am pasting solution here as i am not sure how long the [Link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19772/zipalign-error-executing-tool-executable-location-invalid-android-sdk-tools-23) will be available

> 

- ***Windows***

  Open Android SDK Manager, and ensure that you have "Android SDK
  Build-tools" Rev. 19.1 or 20 installed. If not, install it.

  - Locate your Android SDK folder. You can find this in the error
    message, or you can look in Visual Studio under "Tools -> Options ->
    Xamarin -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location". For this
    example, I'll use:

    %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk
  - Copy zipalign from the build-tools folder:
        %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign Into 
    the tools folder:
         %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign

> **Mac**

Open Android SDK Manager, and ensure that you have "Android SDK Build-tools" Rev. 19.1 or 20 installed. If not, install it.

- Locate your Android SDK folder. You can find this in the error
  message, or you can look in Xamarin Studio under "Xamarin Studio ->
  Preferences -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Android -> Android SDK".
  For this example, I'll use:

  ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx Copy zipalign from the
  build-tools folder:

  ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.1.0/zipalign
  Into the tools folder:

  ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/tools/zipalign